# Cannot get any flamegraph out of perf run. Is function pointer not enough?

Tags: c++, perf, flamegraph

I am running `perf` on a Google Benchmark.
It is compiled with GCC 10 RelWithDebInfo.
I am using CentOS on x86.

Option `--call-graph fp` is the only option that works. Not sure why I cannot go `dwarf`.

Afterward I run the script from:
https://github.com/brendangregg/FlameGraph
To get the flamegraph:

```
perf script | ~/FlameGraph/stackcollapse-perf.pl | ~/FlameGraph/flamegraph.pl > flamegraph.svg
```

This unfortunately says:

```
ERROR: No stack counts found
```

And no flamegraph is produced. However, `perf report` shows percentages and callstack, even if function names are not always there making it hard to interpret.